# Understanding GDB Output from Core Dump?

Tags: java, gdb

I have an application which is having a few stability issues and I'm trying to diagnose root cause, each time the app crashes it produces a Core dump, which I can attach to and view, using GDB. I've attached to the Core Dump and run a backtace, the following information is provided.

```
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New Thread 4263]
[New Thread 4276]
[New Thread 4273]
[New Thread 4272]
[New Thread 4271]
[New Thread 4270]
[New Thread 4269]
[New Thread 4265]
[New Thread 4264]
[New Thread 4262]
[New Thread 4261]
[New Thread 4260]
[New Thread 4256]
[New Thread 4255]
[New Thread 4253]
[New Thread 4252]
Cannot access memory at address 0xfbc6e808
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf7e897af in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

What more can I do to understand what's going on here.. If i do an 'info threads' this seems to show me 16 threads, which I'm making the assumption are in use at time of crash.

How can I get more detail out of the core dump or is that it..

Thanks,
SW

Comment: How you are running the gdb? The warning at the top is something to take in account? Is JNI involved? Does it generates a thread dump too?

If you're using JNI code it may be worth compile it with -g ...

Answer (score 0):

> warning: core file may not match specified executable file.

Are you using the *exact* same executable binary to analyze the core dumps as the one which produced it?

The warning says that you may not be, and without the *exact* binary, the core is mostly useless.

Comment: Yes I'm referencing the binary when executing gdb.. My command is as follows:
    GDB [location_of_command] [crash core]

Comment: This got me thinking, I tried using a different executable and this then returned the exe it was looking for, so it wasn't the one I thought was running - now running the command with the right executable is giving me more info.